# Bessel Function to Exponential Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, bessel-functions

Solving this equation : $ y'' + (1/x)y' - (k^2 - (m^2/x^2) )y=0$ 
gives $y(x) = J_m (-ikx) + Y_m (-ikx)$ which is further written as 
$y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\exp(-kx) + \exp(kx) \right)$

Here $J_m, Y_m$ are Bessel functions of first and second kind respectively & $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Please explain how Bessel functions are converted to exponential form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bessel functions are not converted to exponential form unless $m$ is half-integer.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

---

The differential equation 
\begin{align}
\left[ x^{2} D_{x}^{2} + x D_{x} - ((kx)^{2} - m^{2}) \right] y =0 
\end{align}
has the solution
\begin{align}
y(x) = A J_{im}(-ikx) + B Y_{im}(-i kx)
\end{align} 
where $J_{n}(x)$ and $Y_{n}(x)$ are Bessel functions. Notice that these functions are of order $i m$ which are complex in value.

For the case of $m$ being of fractional order the differential equation
\begin{align}
\left[ x^{2} D_{x}^{2} + 2 x D_{x} + (x^{2} - n(n+1)) \right] y = 0
\end{align}
has the solution 
\begin{align}
y(x) = A j_{n}(x) + B \mathcal{y}_{n}(x).
\end{align}

Further information on the Bessel functions can be obtained, often the starting point these days, from [Bessel Functions (Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

---

As given by the question the solution is
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{2 \, \cosh(kx)}{\sqrt{x}}.
\end{align}
This leads to the differential equation
\begin{align}
x^{2} y'' + x y' - ((kx)^{2} + \frac{1}{4})y = o
\end{align} 
which is a modified Bessel function of fractional order and has the form
\begin{align}
y(x) = A I_{-1/2}(kx) + B I_{1/2}(kx) = A \sqrt{\frac{2}{k\pi x}} \cosh(kx) + B \sqrt{\frac{2}{k\pi x}} \sinh(kx).
\end{align}
From this it is seen that $B=0$ and $A = \sqrt{2 k \pi}$.

---

Another example of similarity:

Consider the solution
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{2}{x^{5}} \, \cosh(kx)
\end{align}
satisfies the differential equation
\begin{align}
x^{2} y'' + 10 x y' -((kx)^{2} - 20)y = 0.
\end{align}
Making the substitution 
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{1}{x^{4}} \, g(x)
\end{align}
it is seen that $g(x)$ satisfies $x^{2} g'' + 2 x g' -(kx)^{2} g = 0$ which has the solution
\begin{align}
g(x) = A j_{0}(-ikx) + B \mathcal{y}_{0}(-ikx) = \frac{1}{x} (A_{1} \sinh(kx) + B_{1} \cosh(kx) ).
\end{align}
This leads to 
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{1}{x^{5}} \left[ A_{1} \sinh(kx) + B_{1} \cosh(kx) \right]. 
\end{align}
Now, letting $A_{1} = 0$ and $B_{1} = 2$ it is then seen that
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{C}{x^{4}} \, \mathcal{y}_{0}(-ikx).
\end{align}

Comment: It is root (x) , i.e. x^(0.5) not x^5 as you write in your solution. Please edit the question to make it root so that other users can be benefited from the same (I am new to math SE).